# How to create link "Post to text file" in WP post?

Tags: wordpress

My main idea is this:

1. Customer browses some article/post.
2. Customer finds a link that says "Download this text + image".
3. Customer clicks on that link.
4. Customer would get a zipped folder, with the post title as folder name (naturally, with the .zip extension at the end), and inside he/she would have available the post image and a text file containing the post text.

Is there any plug-in or easy way to do something like this?
Could someone at least point me in the right direction so I know where to look/learn?

Thanks!

Comment: This is likeaying: "Hi! steal my content." Why would you want that? Making the text file would be easy, but the packaging may be a pain.

Comment: Hi Ryan. Actually, it's a company website that also serves reselling partners. Having our commercial partners "steal" our content to use on their websites will be highly appreciated!! 
But since you're telling me the packaging would be a pain (I'm not an expert...), how would you go about creating/formatting the text file for download?

Comment: See: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/files.php for basics

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're looking for? http://wordpress.org/plugins/export-to-text/